# Is there a faster way to compute the sum of squared distances of two point matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, optimization, difference

I am trying to make the following code run faster.
The code is trying to find the closest frames of two objects by calaculating the sum of squared distance of the two frames every frame has 137 points (x,y).
after filling the distance matrix I am looking for the minimum distance in the matrix and return the indee of this entry.

```
enter code here
def getSquraredDistancesSum(frame1, frame2):
  sum = 0
  distance = 0
  for i in range(0, 137):
      x1 = frame1[i][0]
      y1 = frame1[i][1]
      x2 = frame2[i][0]
      y2 = frame2[i][1]
      sum += math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
  return sum

def get_closest_frames(dataobj1, dataobj2, endpoint, startpoint):
    nf1 = len(dataobj1.body.data)
    nf2 = len(dataobj2.body.data)
    window1size= int(0.15*nf1) 
    window2size = int(0.15*nf2)  
    distancematrix = np.zeros(shape=(window1size, window2size))
    for i in range(endpoint - window1size, endpoint):
      for j in range(startpoint, startpoint + window2size):
        d = getSquraredDistancesSum(dataobj1.body.data[i][0], 
             dataobj2.body.data[j][0])
        distancematrix[i - (endpoint - window1size)][j - startpoint] = d
    min = 1000000
    newstartpoint = startpoint
    newendpoint = endpoint
    for i in range(0, window1size):
      for j in range(0, window2size):
        if distancematrix[i][j] <= min:
            min = distancematrix[i][j]
            newstartpoint = j + startpoint
            newendpoint = i + (endpoint - window1size)
    return newstartpoint, newendpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't follow exactly what the question is trying to achieve.  To take differences between all combinations of two sets of points this may help.  By converting the x and y cordinates to a complex number numpy can handle your frames as 2 1D arrays.  The subtraction generates all f1 - f2 differences.

If this doesn't help try showing a **small** set of test data and expected test results.

```
import numpy as np 

# Create some test data
np.random.seed( 1234 )
frame1 = np.array( [ np.random.rand( ) * 100 + 50,
                     np.random.rand( ) * 100 + 50 ] )

frame2 = np.array( [ np.random.rand( ) * 100 + 50,
                     np.random.rand( ) * 100 + 50 ] )
frame1                                                                                            
# array([[ 69.15194504, 112.2108771 ,  93.7727739 ],
#        [128.53585837, 127.99758081,  77.25926053]])

frame2                                                                                            
# array([[ 77.64642551, 130.18721775, 145.81393537],
#        [137.59326347,  85.781727  , 100.09951255]])


f1 = frame1[ 0 ] + frame1[ 1 ] * 1j  # Make each x & y coord a complex number
f2 = frame2[ 0 ] + frame2[ 1 ] * 1j  # Make each x & y coord a complex number 
f1                                                                                                
# array([ 69.15194504+128.53585837j, 112.2108771 +127.99758081j,
# 93.7727739  +77.25926053j])
f2                                                                                                
# array([ 77.64642551+137.59326347j, 130.18721775 +85.781727j  ,
# 145.81393537+100.09951255j])

differences = f1 - f2[:, None]  # complex differences, 2 dimensions 3 x 3
differences 

# array([[ -8.49448048 -9.0574051j ,  34.56445159 -9.59568266j,
#          16.12634839-60.33400295j],
#        [-61.03527272+42.75413138j, -17.97634065+42.21585382j,
#         -36.41444385 -8.52246647j],
#        [-76.66199033+28.43634582j, -33.60305826+27.89806826j,
#         -52.04116147-22.84025202j]])

distances = np.abs( differences )

print( distances, '\n' )                                                                                    
# [[12.41743878 35.87169413 62.45198975]
#  [74.519932   45.88384396 37.39845125]
#  [81.76604751 43.67456625 56.83273352]] 

print( distances.sum( axis = 0 ), '\n', distances.sum( axis = 1 ) )
#  [168.70341828 125.43010434 156.68317452] # Sum down columns 
#  [110.74112265 157.80222721 182.27334728] # Sum across rows
```